# Euclidean topology: preimage of $(a, b)$ with $a < b \leq 0$

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

I am encountering some difficulties and would like to ask for a hint.
I have a continuous function$$f:R\rightarrow R: f(x)=x^2$$
and am supposed to find preimages of the following intervals

$$1.(a,b) , 0\leq a< b $$
$$2.(a,b) , a < b \leq 0$$
$$3.(a,b) , a \leq 0 <b$$

I am wondering how the function could spit out a negative value as needed in 2. where a is supposed to be strictly smaller than 0.

I apologize, i should add that I do not believe equation 2 to have a preimage, however part 4 of the exercise is then the following:

With the previous results show that $f$ is (topologically) continuous. (Recall that any open set in R can be represented as a union of intervals of the form (a, b) with a < b.).

As I understand, $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous topologically and therefore i don't believe my answer of equation 2 not having a preimage to be correct. Would you be so kind to explain if my understanding is incorrect?

Comment: It couldn't. Therefore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the plus side, you are thinking correctly about the preimage.  This is, roughly, why the definition of a topology requires $\varnothing$ to be open.

For your case (2), you have that $(a,b)$ consists of purely negative numbers.  Hence, as you suspected, $f^{-1}(a,b) = \varnothing$. This is, of course, open.

Comment: but does equation 2 of only having the empty set as preimage not contradict that $x^2$ is continuous? this is my fundamental issue and point of confusion

Comment: No.  The definition of $f: X \to Y$ being continuous is that the inverse image of every open set should be open.  In the event that your open set is like one in case (2), its preimage is STILL open since it is empty.

Comment: To be clear, to check continuity you must check that ALL open sets have open preimages.  You can do this in baby steps by first checking it for all bounded open INTERVALS (the point of your assignment) and then extend the proof by unions.

Comment: thank you Randall!

Comment: What about case  $3$? It can have a pre-image which is neither open nor closed, right?

Comment: @ThomasShelby $(0,+\sqrt{b})$ i believe

Comment: What if  $a\lt 0$? It will be  $[0,\sqrt{b}) $,right?

Comment: @ThomasShelby No.  For example, the preimage of $(-1,2)$ is $(-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$, which is open.

Comment: @Randall Thanks for the clarification.